# Semantic-UI Table, persistent sort

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react, tablesort

Is there a way to make Semantic-UI Table sort to be persistent across multiple component re-renders. For example if I sort ascending by column "Name" is there a way to make this sort stay applied even when my table parent component re-renders ?

Is there a way to do this without messing with table implementation ?

Comment: A little confused with your question.You want the Table could be sorted manually.And after re-render,the sorted you set remain the same?

Comment: The table has sorting functionality implemented, I just need to click in the header of specific column and it will sort by the values for that column. I need that sorting to remain for different data that user gets by clicking on one of the buttons I have next to the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your demand,I have created an example for you.And the output is like in the picture.

[image]

The input and checkbox in the bottom is simulating the user add data.After click on "Submit" button,the data will add in the Table in order automatically.The method to handle the data adding is like the below:

```
addDate1 = () => {

    const { column, data, direction} = this.state
    let addData = {
        name: this.state.inputName,
        age: this.state.inputAge,
        gender: this.state.gender
    }
    let newData = [...data,addData]
    if (!column){
        console.log('Please select a colume')
    } else if (column === 'name'){
        this.setState({
            column: 'name',
            data: _.sortBy(newData, ['name']),
            direction: 'ascending',
        })
    } else if (column === 'age'){
        this.setState({
            column: 'age',
            data: _.sortBy(newData, ['age']),
            direction: 'ascending',
        })
    } else if (column === 'gender'){
        this.setState({
            column: 'gender',
            data: _.sortBy(newData, ['gender']),
            direction: 'ascending',
        })
    } else {
        console.log('error')
    }
}
```

And the working example is in here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/stackOverflow166/setable

Comment: Very nice, I'll be in the office in a few hours and look at it thoroughly. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

For sure, you can set a column name to sort (IE: "Name") and direction ("ASC"/"DESC") in your local state/redux state and then apply sort based on state on each reload.

This is well demonstrated in the DOCS:

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Table } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const tableData = [
  { name: 'John', age: 15, gender: 'Male' },
  { name: 'Amber', age: 40, gender: 'Female' },
  { name: 'Leslie', age: 25, gender: 'Female' },
  { name: 'Ben', age: 70, gender: 'Male' },
]

export default class TableExampleSortable extends Component {
  state = {
    column: null,
    data: tableData,
    direction: null,
  }

  handleSort = clickedColumn => {
    const { column, data, direction } = this.state

    if (column !== clickedColumn) {
      this.setState({
        column: clickedColumn,
        data: _.sortBy(data, [clickedColumn]),
        direction: 'ascending',
      })

      return
    }

    this.setState({
      data: data.reverse(),
      direction: direction === 'ascending' ? 'descending' : 'ascending',
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { column, data, direction } = this.state

    return (
      <Table sortable celled fixed>
        <Table.Header>
          <Table.Row>
            <Table.HeaderCell
              sorted={column === 'name' ? direction : null}
              onClick={this.handleSort('name')}
            >
              Name
            </Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell
              sorted={column === 'age' ? direction : null}
              onClick={this.handleSort('age')}
            >
              Age
            </Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell
              sorted={column === 'gender' ? direction : null}
              onClick={this.handleSort('gender')}
            >
              Gender
            </Table.HeaderCell>
          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Header>
        <Table.Body>
          {_.map(data, ({ age, gender, name }) => (
            <Table.Row key={name}>
              <Table.Cell>{name}</Table.Cell>
              <Table.Cell>{age}</Table.Cell>
              <Table.Cell>{gender}</Table.Cell>
            </Table.Row>
          ))}
        </Table.Body>
      </Table>
    )
  }
}
```

Ref: https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table/#variations-sortable

Comment: Currently in office, will take more detailed look sometime tomorrow and will report back.

Comment: Ok, this is a standard pattern, I'll wait for your feedback about it

Comment: Thank you for your example, I decided to go with Root's answer.